# is possible post data from android to node js?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, post

i use **node.js** as server and android as client, the server work normally send and receive data from client (except android)

here my code in javascript

```
function put(id, data, callback) {
    $.ajax('http://mydomain.com:8888/' + id + '/', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (callback)
                callback(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            if (callback)
                callback(false);
        }
    });
}
```

and my node script

```
function handler ( req, res ) {
    if ( req.method === 'POST' ) {
       console.log('receive data from post');
    }
}
```

the code above has successfully sent data.

i want to send data (post) to node (like what javascript does) in android?

how i achieve that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But of course

[Here you go](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }
}
```

Comment: how about array ? if i want send array value to server, how the code in android,,maybe nameValuePairs will be change to another code ?